# Protractor, iterating elements: Failed: stale element reference

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, webdriver, protractor

I have an array of webdriver elements, I am trying to iterate over them to delete them all, except the one with index 0. The processes inside this iteration are asynchronous.

I have tried several things, but none seem to work.

My current approach is to use a `for of` loop, but I am getting a `Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

```
const els = await this.el.getElements(this.s.tm.button.remove)

for (let el of els) {
      if (els.indexOf(el) >= 1) {
        await this.h.waitForSpinner(2147483647)
        await el.click()
        await EC.isVisible(this.s.tm.deleteModal.container)
        await this.h.waitForSpinner(2147483647)
        await this.el.clickElement(this.s.tm.deleteModal.confirmButton)
      }
    }
```

I have also tried to use:

```
element.all(by.css('[data-qa="this.s.tm.button.remove"]')).filter((el, i) => {
      return i >= 1;
    }).each(async (el, i) => {
      await el.click()
      await EC.isVisible(this.s.tm.deleteModal.container)
      await this.h.waitForSpinner(50000)
      await this.el.clickElement(this.s.tm.deleteModal.confirmButton)
    });
```

But this second approach is not awaiting for the async code.

Any help will be appreciated!

**=================== UPDATED SOLUTION ===================**

The solution to iterate over a WebDriver collection of elements by @yong is correct.

However, in my case, the code inside the `for loop` is **deleting one element** each time, so there is a moment in which `.get(i)` tries to get an index provided by the loop that no longer exists in the page. Getting the error:

`Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 6, but there are only 5 elements that match locator By(css selector, [data-qa=team-members__button-remove])`.

The solution is to use a decremental `for loop`. This means, the loop backwards of `els_count` will match always the `get(i)`. Note that if `els_count === 10`, the last index will be 9. So we need to do `els_count - 1`.

```
async deleteAllTeamMembers() {
  await EC.isVisible(await this.el.getFirstElement(this.s.tm.button.invite));
  const els_count = await this.el.getElements(this.s.tm.button.remove).count();

for (let i = els_count - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
  await EC.isVisible(this.el.getElements(this.s.tm.button.remove).get(i))
  await this.el.getElements(this.s.tm.button.remove).get(i).click()
  await EC.isVisible(this.s.tm.deleteModal.confirmButton, 50000)
  await this.el.clickElement(this.s.tm.deleteModal.confirmButton)
  await this.h.waitForSpinner(50000)
}
```

}

Comment: The key point of your problem is every time you click the element, it trigger the page happen changes, this will make selenium treat the page  as an new page, not the same page as the one of previous loop so all elements found in previous loop or before first loop can't be used in new page.  For example: the `els` has two elements, after click the `els[0]`,  an new page arrive,  the `els[1]` is found at the init page not the new page, so you can't continue to use `els[1]` at new page, you have to find it again if you want to use it on new page.  If you use it,  Stale Reference Error throw out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const els_cnt = await element.all(by.css('[data-qa="this.s.tm.button.remove"]')).count();

for (let index=1;index<els_cnt;index++) {
    await element.all(by.css('[data-qa="this.s.tm.button.remove"]')).get(index).click();
    await EC.isVisible(this.s.tm.deleteModal.container)
    await this.h.waitForSpinner(50000)
    await this.el.clickElement(this.s.tm.deleteModal.confirmButton)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Hold the elements in the object and you need to access each element asynchronously and perform action as shown below. Dont need to specify waits

```
this.searchResults = element.all(by.xpath('<xpath>') // this will hold array of elements

function foo(){
this.searchResults.then(function(runTimeResults){
            for(i=0; i< runTimeResults.length; i++){
                if(i>0){ //click/delete the element if the index > 0
                (function(currentElement){
                    currentElement.click();                 
                    });
                })(runTimeResults[i]);// Need to hold the current ith element in a variable => currentElement
                }
            };
        });
}
```